# Somethings wrong with my code TEXTVIEW

Tags: android, textview, radio-button, radio-group

Please help me what I want to do is whenever I clicked a radiobutton the variables increase it's value so i create a method like this but every time I clicked the button the app unfortunately stops.

```
public void verbal1(){
  verbalSc = verbalSc + 1;
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    verScore.setText(Integer.toString(verbalSc));

}
```

Comment: put your stacktrace here

Comment: post your details code

Comment: can you put hole code in stack overflow.

Comment: Please read: [Unfortunately MyApp has Stopped How Can I Solve This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `verScore` has the reference of `TextView` in XML.

**Try this:**

```
int verbalSc = 0;
TextView verScore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...........
    .................
    verScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
}

public void verbal1(){
    verbalSc = verbalSc + 1;
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    verScore.setText(Integer.toString(verbalSc));
}
```

Comment: @xhen If my answer seems useful then please give an up-vote. Thanks in advance :)